# Analyse categorical data against boolean

Tags: r, analytics

I have a dataframe in R that holds the following data

```
> df3
    care_uncare              risks
1            No High risk patients
2           Yes High risk patients
3           Yes High risk patients
4           Yes High risk patients
5           Yes  Low risk patients
6           Yes  Low risk patients
7            No  Low risk patients
8           Yes High risk patients
9           Yes  Low risk patients
10          Yes  Low risk patients
11          Yes High risk patients
12          Yes  Low risk patients
13           No  Low risk patients
14          Yes  Low risk patients
15          Yes  Low risk patients
16          Yes High risk patients
```

Where care_uncare variable holds Yes/No values and the risks variable holds High risk patients/Low risk patients.

I want to do generate a summary or visualisation that shows the total number of patients having care_uncare as 'Yes' but having risks as 'High risk patients'

How can I do this analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` and `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(care_uncare == "Yes" & risks == "High risk patients") %>%
summarise( Total_Yes_High = n() )

  a     care_uncare risks             
  <chr> <chr>       <chr>             
1 2     Yes         High risk patients
2 3     Yes         High risk patients
3 4     Yes         High risk patients
4 8     Yes         High risk patients
5 11    Yes         High risk patients
6 16    Yes         High risk patients
```

Answer (score 0):

this can easily with this:

```
df3 %>% group_by(care_uncare, risks) %>% summarise( n = n() )
```